# sas hdd + ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hard-drive

I'm desperate cause i need to run a sas drive in a ubuntu 18.04 and i cannot because i know very little on linux/ubuntu.
This pc has a controller sas fastrak tx2650 and ubuntu 18.04 .
When i'm logged i run commands to list memory devices (fdisk -l and lsblk) but the hdd is not listed. If i run the hdd under window it is listed correctly. So what can i do? Is the controller not working in ubuntu? What can i do to let the hdd be shown as device?
Totally confused. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: There are [drivers for RedHat and SuSE Linux](https://www.promise.com/Search?query=tx2650), but nothing for Ubuntu (or Debian). You *may* be able to use the partially-open kernel driver, but that was made for a much older kernel than 18.04 uses. You may be on your own with this one ...

Comment: Promise Technologies is bad with Ubuntu drivers.  However, you can run `sudo lshw -C storage` and see if Ubuntu had loaded a Kernel driver to see that controller.  If not, you really might be on your own.

Comment: $ sudo lshw -C storage
[sudo] password ...:
*-storage
description: RAID bus controller
product: PDC42819 [FastTrak TX2650/TX4650]
vendor: Promise Technology, Inc.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 00
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: storage pm pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver-ahci latency-
resources: irq:16 loport:cc00(size=128) ioport:c800(size=256) memory:fceff000-F
ec0000-fcedffff memory: fcefc000-fcefdfff memory:fce80000-fcebffff
...

Comment: It seems raid controller is detected? But now what can i do?

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1454172/edit) your question and add that output?  Also add the output of the commands `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo parted -l`.  There is still a chance that the `driver-ahci` may not be compatible with that controller.  I honestly have not had good luck with Promise Technologies much after my DOS and Windows days, and Promise was one of my favorite hard drive controllers back in the day.